# Axis labels troubles

Tags: pgfplots, axis

I am new in LaTex and have some troubles with pgfplots. Why one of X axis label just **5*10^-2**, it would be great if I could fix that problem.

[image: Plot image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{title = Зависимость потерь давления $\Delta p$ от расхода воздуха $Q$}\label{fig:3}
\begin{axis}[
    table/col sep = semicolon,
    grid = major,
    xlabel = {$\text{Расход воздуха } Q$, $\text{м}^3/\text{с}$},
    ylabel = {$\text{Потери давления $\Delta p$, кПа}$},
    height = 0.38\paperheight, 
    width = 0.75\paperwidth,
    %xmin = -0.5, xmax = 45,
    minor tick num = 4,
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={}]
\addplot table[mark=none, y = {Lost Pressure}, x= {Rate}]{air_pressure_table.csv};
\addplot  [only marks]coordinates{(0.1, 2.1442184245623506) (0.25, 12.886964033484505) (0.4, 32.83777730719707)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

P.S. Sorry, if style of this post is bad, i'm new on this site :D. I tried to found some post with the same problem, but no results(

Comment: Welcome! Please provide the code as a minimum working example. People will have a easier time on helping you solve the issue. For the code right now, because we don't have the access of the file `air_pressure_table.csv` and we are not sure the language you are using. It's hard to reproduce the issue you have in our end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

- Please always provide complete small but complete, compilable document (MWE: Minimal Working Example) with your diagram which we can test as it is.
- Your problem you can solve with adding `/pgf/number format/fixed` to your diagram preamble (axis options).
- Since MWE is unknown, I use only part of your diagram code (removed part doesn't influence on solution of your problem).

**Edit**
Added are package which enables to write Russian fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    height = 0.38\paperheight,
    width = 0.75\paperwidth,
%
    grid = major,
    title = {Зависимость потерь давления $\Delta p$ от расхода воздуха $Q$},  
    xlabel = {$\text{Расход воздуха } Q$, $\text{м}^3/\text{с}$},
    ylabel = {$\text{Потери давления $\Delta p$, кПа}$},
    minor tick num = 4,
    /pgf/number format/fixed   % <---
    ]
\addplot  [only marks] coordinates {(0.1, 2.1442184245623506) (0.25, 12.886964033484505) (0.4, 32.83777730719707)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]